# Ubuntu on Vbox and Rails -- "Please install tilt-1.3.3"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rubygems

I have no idea why Ubuntu I installed on my VBox still coughs up the famous error message "Please install tilt-1.3.3, because you don't have it, you can't use -rails server-"
That is really odd to me because I already run into this error in Mint and have no way out, I was thinking Ubuntu could have resolved it but now I am stuck on it again.

Comment: Have you tried _installing tilt_: `gem install title`?

Comment: How did you install Ruby on Rails? Should you install the distribution-provided `ruby-tilt` package or should you install a `tilt` gem via `bundler` or something similar?

Comment: @sarnold, I only run `apt-get install ruby`

Comment: @dunsmoreb, I run that command and into an error "could not find a title (>=0)"

Comment: @solomon I'm sorry, you should install `tilt`.

Comment: It displays the same error after I issue `gem install tilt`

Comment: Add the output of these to your question: `ruby -v`, `gem env`.

Answer (score 1):

Historically I've had trouble deploying to ubuntu myself, and I'm wondering if there is a particular reason for installing ruby via apt-get as opposed to, say, RVM?

If not, have you tried an RVM based ruby install and do you receive the same error message:
https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Some additional details you may want to consider if you decide to take the RVM route on Ubuntu 12.04
http://bit.ly/ISzOB2

Comment: Actually, I would advice using [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) together with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) instead of `rvm`. See here for some of the [key differences](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#in-contrast-with-rvm-rbenv-does-not%E2%80%A6).